# In what format should I store date/times in Firebase to ensure accuracy?

Tags: database, firebase, datetime, google-cloud-firestore

Below is what I'm currently using to write. Would this work? This outputs a date as `1663028866561`.

```
final String timestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
```

Comment: I'll quickly point out that you have three distinct questions in this post.  One is asking an opinion about what to store, one is asking what is the difference between something you're showing and something else you're not showing (a long version with more zeroes?), and another is asking about date/time formatting.  I suggest removing the question asking for opinion, as that's off topic for Stack Overflow, and split the other two questions into different posts for clarity on what the issue is in each case.  You should a also clarify what programming language you're using.

Comment: @DougStevenson ok I'll clean this up. Thanks Doug.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @AlexMamo I modified the question